# Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-library

I am trying to update my library for the project by adding following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1"
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error as:

**Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19

Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12**

Comment: try 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' thats the one I use and it works flawlessly.

Comment: What about using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurred because you used jar file that is [deprecated and no longer being maintained](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley#deprecated).

Use this to include volley library:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

instead of `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` as volley dependency.

Comment: Is 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' is older than mcxiaoke v1.0.19 or they are different versioning systems?

Answer (score 1):

Keep tracking here: https://github.com/google/volley
for now it's:

```
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add mavenCentral() at project level build gradle file** `

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir}
```